# How to set up session in vuejs django after successful login?

Tags: javascript, django, session, vue.js, vue-component

If login is successful i need to redirect to a login success page and I need to include a session in that.. How can it be possible. I am using html with vue js for front end and back end is django.

This is my vue js script for login.

```
<script>
logBox = new Vue({
el: "#logBox",
  data: {
   email : '',
   password: '',
   response: {
        authentication : '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
     handelSubmit: function(e) {
           var vm = this;
           data = {};
           data['email'] = this.email;
           data['password'] = this.password;
            $.ajax({
              url: '/login/',
              data: data,
              type: "POST",
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(e) {
              if(e.status){
               alert("Login Success");
            // Redirect the user
            window.location.href = "/loginsuccess/";
             }
              else {
                 vm.response = e;
                alert("failed to login!");
              }
          }
            });
            return false;
}
},
});
 </script>
```

So, how can I include session in login successpage.. This is the first time I am doing a work.. Please help me ..

Answer (score 1):

If you are not doing a SPA, you can use the usual way of store sessions, put the session token in a cookie (the server is the responsible of doing when a successful login request happens). The next time the user do a request the cookie will send automatically to the server.

If you are doing a SPA, you can store the session token in the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). In this case, you should configure the ajax calls to set a header with the token or any other way you prefer to send the token to the server.